# AM3354 USB communication error

Tags: microcontroller, usb

I have here a Ti AM3354 microcontroller that is connected to a bluetooth controller nRF52840 via USB interface. On debugging on the usb connection with a logic analyzer I recognized, that at irregular intervals some usb packages are faulty. See the following pictures. The first picture shows a correct usb package. The second picture shows a faulty usb package. On the second picture a timing inconsistency on the D+ line can be recognized.

[image: USB packet with no errors.]

[image: USb packet with errors.]

Now I'm wondering what the cause for this behavior is.
Does anyone have any idea where I can start troubleshooting?

Comment: Isn't the first one also faulty at the right hand side?

Comment: What's the sampling rate of the logic analyzer? What's the USB data rate on the bus?

Comment: @Andyaka The signal is correct. End of packet (EOP) signaling uses single-ended line states and is no longer differential.

Comment: @Justme The sampling rate is 24Ms/s and the bus speed is 12Mbps (Full-Speed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a communication error.

You are using the logic analyzer at 24 Msps which is too low to sample a 12 Mbps bus properly.